# Problem with MySQL JSON Functions to Create Grouped Data

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have the following simple JSON structure in MySQL.

```
{"person_main":{"name_first": "Mike"}}
```

I want to add a GROUP of Skills for this "person_main" record so it reads:

```
{"person_main":{"name_first": "Mike", 
 "skills": [
  {"Name": "Learning", "Proficiency": 3}, 
  {"Name": "Teaching", "Proficiency": 2}
]}}
```

I cannot figure out how to insert the "Skills" data as group content into the base JSON structure **using MySQL JSON functions**.

While the below code doesn't work, what I want to do is:

```
SET @tempvar = '{"person_main":{"name_first": "Mike"}}';
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0].Name', 'Learning');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0].Proficiency', '3');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[1].Name', 'Teaching');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[1].Proficiency', 2);
```

How on earth do I accomplish this with MySQL? I simply want to build a group of content within a sub field that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Why not just: `SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills', '[
  {"Name": "Learning", "Proficiency": 3}, 
  {"Name": "Teaching", "Proficiency": 2}
]')`?

Comment: Because I'm writing code that must dynamically convert from one JSON structure to another and build the groups using different names. I can't hardcode it like that. This includes iterating through the group index entries and copying each field one at a time.

Comment: Then you should maybe show us the code that builds the structure. Is it SQL, or something else? If it's SQL, there are MySQL functions to generate JSON from data structures.

Comment: I just need to know how to do the above; create/add a group of content to an existing data structure. I don't want to complicate things beyond this because this is all I need to know how to do. Note that READING the JSON using the above format works perfectly fine. It's creating/writing/appending it that isn't working at all, and every single sample I see online only has FLAT array samples without any internal object structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use

```
JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0].Name', 'Learning');
```

because the `skills` array doesn't exist when you try to do the `JSON_SET`. You can manually create all the pieces before attempting to set them but it's probably easier to use `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_OBJECT`:

```
SET @tempvar = '{"person_main":{"name_first": "Mike"}}';

SET @tempvar = JSON_INSERT(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills', 
                               JSON_ARRAY(
                                   JSON_OBJECT('Name', 'Learning', 'Proficiency', 3),
                                   JSON_OBJECT('Name', 'Teaching', 'Proficiency', 2)
                               )
                           );

SELECT @tempvar;
```

Output:

```
{"person_main": {"skills": [{"Name": "Learning", "Proficiency": 3}, {"Name": "Teaching", "Proficiency": 2}], "name_first": "Mike"}}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=37a74a823ca110a17192166bc6c46bac)

If you must use code in the style you have described, then you have to manually create each piece before attempting to set its values:

```
SET @tempvar = '{"person_main":{"name_first": "Mike"}}';
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills', JSON_ARRAY());
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0]', JSON_OBJECT());
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0].Name', 'Learning');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[0].Proficiency', '3');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[1]', JSON_OBJECT());
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[1].Name', 'Teaching');
SET @tempvar = JSON_SET(@tempvar, '$.person_main.skills[1].Proficiency', 2);
SELECT @tempvar;
```

Output:

```
{"person_main": {"skills": [{"Name": "Learning", "Proficiency": "3"}, {"Name": "Teaching", "Proficiency": 2}], "name_first": "Mike"}}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8a232e33a56195830c52fe1d05a806e9)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed (I was working a similar solution as you posted). Thank you VERY much for clarifying! It's sad that I couldn't find a single example that was similar to what you posted, especially in the MySQL documentation; everything they have is so generic and flat, there's nothing "nested" or complex in any capacity. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @Nick, what's the best approach for copying one JSON structure to another with multiple nested arrays? From what I can tell, the only way to do this is to parse the JSON string data (e.g. $x.y[z].field) manually and recreate it using the above technique, but this quickly turns into a problem when we have arrays within arrays. Is the only way to do this to write a parsing system in MySQL to walk the structure and build it out using JSON_X functions?

Comment: @Floobinator yes - it's a monumental pain. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601014/mysql-json-merge-two-json-objects-primary-key-in-json-document/60601722#comment107215067_60601722

Comment: @Floobinator I suggest you open a new question. I'm going away for  a couple of days so you might be able to get a (better) answer from someone else in the meantime.

Comment: Hey @Nick, thanks a ton for the feedback; I actually already got it all written and working. I just needed a starting point. Travel safe!